# How to install libboost-all-dev v1.40 Debian wheezy

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, libraries

I'm new here. I need to `install libboost-all-dev` package that contains this stuff: `libboost1.40-dev libboost-system1.40-dev libboost-filesystem1.40-dev libboost-date-time1.40-dev libboost-regex1.40-dev libboost-thread1.40-dev` exactly in this version but on my Debian 7 wheezy I have `libboost-all-dev` in `1.4.9` version how can I change it and install package that i need so much. 
Here is my `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Why do you need 1.4?  Can you not use 1.49?  Squeeze(Oldstable) only gets you to 1.42.  See this [package search result](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libboost-all-dev).  See also [Install boost version 1.40](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180167/install-boost-version-1-40)

Comment: I was going to ask the same... if you have 1.49 dev files installed, you should be able to remove them with apt-get remove. Then you can download 1.40 from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_40_0.html, and compile it. However it's very possible that you break something else on the way...

Comment: I'm with @Arimo on this one... libboost is a toolchain package.  GCC may have an indirect/direct dependency on it, therefore downgrading a live system without using a changeroot will break GCC, which will break all of Debian

Answer (score 0):

You can find old packages in the [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/boost-defaults/1.40.0.1/) archive. However, downgrading packages is generally not supported in Debian, so if anything breaks, you've got to keep the pieces. I also recommend using a separate chroot for such experiments.

Comment: But how can i install this package from snapshots?

Comment: Simplest is to downloaded all required `.deb` files and install them via `dpkg -i *.deb`. Another possibility is adding the given archive snapshot to your `sources.list` as explained on the [main page](http://snapshot.debian.org/).